# How to allow that permission in Glassfish

Tags: java, security, glassfish, neo4j, policy

On my Glassfish server, I have recently enabled security manager. As soon as i've done that, the [neo4j-JCA connector](http://alexsmirnov.wordpress.com/2011/05/18/neo4j-java-ee-connector/) I use has stopped working, complaining with that exception :

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.management.ManagementPermission monitor)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at sun.management.ManagementFactory.checkAccess(ManagementFactory.java:223)
    at sun.management.ManagementFactory.checkMonitorAccess(ManagementFactory.java:228)
    at sun.management.RuntimeImpl.getBootClassPath(RuntimeImpl.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ConfigurationLogging.logConfig(ConfigurationLogging.java:91)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.GraphDbInstance.start(GraphDbInstance.java:166)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDbImpl.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDbImpl.java:190)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:80)
    at com.netoprise.neo4j.Neo4jManagedConnectionFactory.createDatabase(Neo4jManagedConnectionFactory.java:278)
    at com.netoprise.neo4j.Neo4jManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(Neo4jManagedConnectionFactory.java:154)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.ConnectorAllocator.createResource(ConnectorAllocator.java:160)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:907)
    ... 74 more
```

I've understood I have to write something in my server.policy, but what ? I have tried

```
//Neo4J management permission for logging
grant  codeBase "file:${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/neo4j-connector-0.3-SNAPSHOT/-"{
      permission java.lang.management.ManagementPermission "monitor";
};
```

With absolutely no effect. So what syntax should I use ? (notice `neo4j-connector-0.3-SNAPSHOT` is name of the JCA connector for Neo4J

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the permissions in the JCA descriptor file ra.xml. Here's an [example](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/An_Overview_of_the_JBossCX_Architecture-A_Sample_Skeleton_JCA_Resource_Adaptor.html):

```
        <security-permission>
            <security-permission-spec> permission java.io.FilePermission
                "/tmp/db/fs_store/*", "read,write"; 
            </security-permission-spec>
        </security-permission>
```

Comment: Is it normal you add a FilePermission when Glassfish complains about a ManagementPermission ?

Comment: This was just an example. Add the correct permissions that your adapter requires.